# jQuery TreeView Control with Checkbox + DotNet

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

Looking for a ***free*** jQuery TreeView control supporting all the below mentioned features. Need to use the same in ASP.NET.

Mandatory:

1. Cross Browser Compatible (minimum IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari)
2. Data Source as JSON Data
3. Drag & Drop feature
4. Tree Nodes with Checkbox
5. Selectable, AutoOpen/Expand/Unexpand All

Optional:

1. Right Click Context Menu
2. Tree Nodes with Icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bassistance jquery-plugin-treeview.You can get documentation and download hear.
  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/